# simulate submit of another form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application view with a view like this

```
  = form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => "ratings_form" do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @filter.include?(rating)
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => "ratings_submit"
```

and later in the same view a link

```
link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => :title)
```

What I would like to do is when I click the link `Movie Title`, is there anyway I can add the parameters of the `ratings_form` to the URL too? So I can access those in the controller too

Eg.
Ratings Form submit = `/movies?ratings[G]=1&commit=Refresh`
Clicking the link = `/movies?sort=release_date`

I would like `ratings[G]=1` (or any selected checkboxes) to be in the URL when i click the link too.

Is there any elegant way to do this in rails?

Rails Version : 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => :title), onclick: "submit_ratings_form($(this));"

# some jQuery to add the params to the form and submit it:
var submit_ratings_form = function(a_tag) {
  var params = a_tag.href.split('?')[1];
  var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", params.split('=')[0]).val(params.split('=')[1]);
  $('#ratings_form').append($(input));
  $('#ratings_form').submit();
}
```

This code assumes that you have only one param in the link_to?

Comment: Thanks so i guess the only way to do it is using javascript. I was looking for a ruby solution but this works too.

Comment: I don't think there is a Ruby solution. Ruby is on the server-side, here you want to "update" the form before submitting it, a client-side operation ;)

Comment: Yes now i get it. Just started learning rails. Enjoying it so far. anyways thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1:**

Well I believe you can do something like this:

my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]

```
link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => :title, :ratings=> my_array)
```

**Alternative 2:**

Create a form with a link which calls the submit on the form via JS. The code in view looks something like this:

```
<% form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => 'movie_'+arr.to_s do |f|%>    
        <%= hidden_field_tag('ratings[]', arr[0]) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag('ratings[]', arr[1]) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag('ratings[]', arr[2]) %>
        <%= link_to_function 'Movie Title', "document.getElementById('movie_"+arr.to_s+"').submit()"%>
      <%end%>
```

The **form id** is used to identify which submit to call in the JS (since there may be an arbitrary number of forms). It can be anything unique per form.